# Trigger for Content Version (SNOTE) before Insert

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, contentversion

I need to prevent ALL Users from creating a new Enhanced Note (we ended up creating our own object because we needed more customization).  I'm trying to write a trigger but am getting stuck on an error. Any help would be apprediated!

```
trigger NoteBlockCreate on ContentVersion (before insert) {
for(ContentVersion cv:trigger.new){
    if(cv.FileType = 'SNOTE')
    {
        cv.adderror('Please use new notes');
    }
}
}
```

The error I get is: **Field is not writeable: ContentVersion.FileType**

Comment: For comparison , you need to use == operator. 
Like - cv.FileType == 'SNOTE' in your if statement.

Comment: Of course! I'm so out of practice. Thank you!  Unfortunately the trigger is not working when I test do you happen to have any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest you to use String comparison operators listed here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm
Try adding System.debug() for checking the comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to compare one value to another, the proper syntax is:

```
if (version.FileType == 'SNOTE')
```

When you use only one `=`, it is an assignment rather than a comparison. Note that it is highly recommended to use whole words in your variable names.

Comment: Anecdotally, every time I read `cv` in code, I can't help but think of a resume (I watch way too much British programming). The designers of Apex gave us a symbol length of 40 characters, so we may as well be as descriptive as necessary.

Comment: I'm the outlier here; I'm perfectly happy with `cv` for `ContentVersion` and `cdl` for `ContentDocumentLink`; especially in short vertical space `for` loops

Comment: It's so little benefit and you force the reader to interpret what could be explicit and straightforward.